Create an object field using Mongoose schema and apply basic Mongoose validations to the fields of the object field in NestJS
I have a 'User' schema which has the 'contact' field of object type. One of the fields of the contact (address) field is also an object. 'address' is also the object type and has some desired fields. So I have made schema accordingly.
Sample payload:
{
  name: 'Clark',
  contact: {
     phone: 876543212,
     address: {
       doorNo: 4,
       street: '',
       city: '',
       pincode: 123456
     }
  }
}

Schema:
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema({ _id: false })
class ContactDetails {
  @Prop({ type: Number, required: true })
  phone: number;

  @Prop({ type: Object, required: true })
  Address: {
    type: {
      doorNo: {
        type: string;
        required: true;
      };
    
      street: {
        type: string;
        required: true;
      };
      
      city: {
        type: CityEnum;
        required: true;
      };

      pincode: number;
    };
  };
}

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: ContactDetails, required: true })
  contact: ContactDetails;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

The record is created in the database properly. But when I test by not passing any of the required fields of the 'address', I'm not getting appropriate error (for required). So I recognised that the schema validation is not happening for the nested schema which is 'ContactDetails' above.
So I tried an alternate approach by creating schema for address as 'AddressDetails' so that I can directly apply the @Prop validation for the address fields. But still the errors are not thrown if any of the required address fields is missing.
@Schema({ _id: false })
class AddressDetails {
  @Prop({ type: Number, required: true })
  doorNo: number;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  street: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: CityEnum, required: true })
  city: CityEnum;

  @Prop({ type: Number })
  pincode: number;
}

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: Object, required: true })
  contact: {
    type: {
      phone: String;
      address: { type: AddressDetails, required: true };
    };
  };
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

I want a properly working schema which captures and throws error if any of the required fields is not passed to the nested schema.
Kindly provide me a solution for the above and Thanks in advance!

I figured out the solution myself just in 30 mins after asking the question.
It is the @Props that needs to be passed with appropriate types. If the nested path or nested schema should also be validated with appropriate type and required or not.
Method 1: Nested Schema containing Nested path.
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema({
  _id: false
})
class ContactDetails {
  @Prop({
    type: Number,
    required: true
  })
  phone: number;

  @Prop({
    type: {
      doorNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }

      street: {
        type: String;
        required: true;
      };

      city: {
        type: String;
        enum: CityEnum;
        required: true;
      };

      pincode: Number;

    },
    _id: false
  })
  Address: {
    type: {
      doorNo: {
        type: string;
        required: true;
      };

      street: {
        type: string;
        required: true;
      };

      city: {
        type: string;
        enum: CityEnum;
        required: true;
      };

      pincode: number;
    };
  };
}

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true
  })
  name: string;

  @Prop({
    type: ContactDetails,
    required: true
  })
  contact: ContactDetails;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

Similarly for method 2, a nestjs mongoose schema should be created and passed to the type in the @Props along with passing the nested schema's class in the actual field's (address) type.
Method 2: Nested Path containing Nested Schema.
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema({
  _id: false
})
class AddressDetails {
  @Prop({
    type: Number,
    required: true
  })
  doorNo: number;

  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true
  })
  street: string;

  @Prop({
    type: String,
    enum: CityEnum,
    required: true
  })
  city: CityEnum;

  @Prop({
    type: Number
  })
  pincode: number;
}

const addressDetailsSchema = SchemaFactory.CreateForClass(AddressDetails);

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true
  })
  name: string;

  @Prop({
    type: {
      phone: Number
      address: addressDetailsSchema
    },
    _id: false
  })
  contact: {
    type: {
      phone: number;
      address: {
        type: AddressDetails,
        required: true
      };
    };
  };
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

As you can see among the above two methods, method 1 is readable and hence preferring it.
Happy coding!
